# Compare RRule String if it is overlapping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rrule

I want to have a checker between two RRule string if they are overlapping.For example:

RRUle String 1 : DTSTART:20200901T150000Z\nRRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=30;INTERVAL=1;WKST=MO
RRUle String 2 : DTSTART:20200902T150000Z\nRRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=30;INTERVAL=1;WKST=MO

Is there a way to know if its overlapping based on RRule String?

Comment: were you able to find solution for this ?